# Xamarin TouchID custom popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, popup, touch-id

i'm implementing authentication via TouchId in a Xamarin-App on iOS.
I followed this example which is working fine;
 https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_touchid/

But is it possible to replace the popup invoked by EvaluatePolicy by my own custom popup?

Greetings
Michael

Answer (score 2):

No, the popup is run out-of-process for security purposes.  It also allows you to support FaceID and passcode automatically.

You can customize the message that is shown though through changing the value in the localizedReason field.